Need help identifying the maker of this 3 wheel adult tricycle
I want to buy this adult tricycle, but the owner cannot find the brand. Can someone recognize it?


Does the brand matter to your purchasing decision?  Comfort and fit are top priority, and build quality is a close third.   I'd give the bike a good M check and make sure there are no obvious flaws/damage and that everything works as expected.   Most bikes have fairly interchangeable parts - its not like a car in that respect.

Are there any logos or unique style points to share (with an additional photo)?

A quick reverse image search returns Viribus, or to be specific, a Viribus Adult Tricycle 7-Speed, Single-Chain.
There are many brands with the same or a similar frame design, but I could find this particular combination of colors only with Viribus.

Good idea with the image search.  I found https://www.walmart.com/ip/FICISOG-26-Adult-Tricycle-3-Wheel-7-Speed-Bikes-450lbs-Capacity-Cruise-Trike-with-Shopping-Basket/457983082 and https://www.homedepot.com/p/24-in-3-Wheel-Bikes-for-Adults-7-Speed-Adult-Trikes-Bicycles-Cruise-Trike-with-Shopping-Basket-for-Seniors-Women-Men-N-P24-QL/321390055   as well, so its a common frame design with a lot of re-branding.  Literally the brands are made-up words like "ficisog"

@Criggie haha yes, I just found similar bikes named Pexmor, Vevor, Docred, Slsy, Artudatech, Mooncool and Mophoto. AI generated I suppose ;-)
